# Is every basis a frame?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

It's clear that every orthonormal basis is a frame, but is **every** basis a frame? In particular, is a non-orthogonal basis always a frame? If yes, why?

I'm asking about general Hilbert spaces, in particular infinite dimensional spaces.

Comment: Do you mean basis as in hamel basis?

Comment: @user251257 I meant a countable (i.e. Schauder) basis, sorry, should have clarified that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $(e_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ be an ONB for a Hilbert space. $(\frac{1}{n}e_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is spanning and representation is unique, i.e., it is a basis. But it is not a frame, since 
$$
\sum_{n\in \mathbb N} \left|\langle e_k, \frac{1}{n}e_n \rangle\right|^2 \leq \frac{1}{k^2}.
$$

Comment: I didn't noticed thet the OP was referring also to infinite dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: Maybe he wasn't. In that case you are of course correct.

Comment: I just noticed now the tag for functional-analisys, thus I think that the OP was referring to the general case.

Comment: Oh you are right, that's a good indication.

Comment: Yes, I was asking about the general case. Sorry for the confusion, I edited my question. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: In your inequality above though, it mustn't be e_n in the first entry of the inner product. The index cannot be n. I wanted to edit the index to k, but edits must affect at least 6 characters, how annoying.

Comment: Yes, of course. I fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: Now I'm confused. This is what Wikipedia says on the page about frames in the subsection "Exact Frames": "Each basis for an inner product space is an exact frame for the space (so a basis is a special case of a frame)." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_(linear_algebra). How does that statement fit with the example above?

Comment: Of course it is possible, that I missed something, but I believe my argument is sound. The thing is that you need to be careful with your definition of a basis. I was talking about a spanning set where representation is unique. Some call this $\omega$- independence. Another concept is that of a Riesz basis. This is indeed always a frame. In finite dimensions, as also explained in gimusi's answer, every basis is a Riesz basis. In the wikipedia article it is not directly apparent which definition of a basis is used, though.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I guess what it comes down to is that this part of the Wikipedia article on frames just isn't very good, since the statement is both imprecise and without any proof. Your example, on the other hand, is precise and correct as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

For finite dimensional vector spaces every basis is a frame in the sense that we can describe all the space in an unique manner by any basis.

For non orthogonal basis we lost the property that

$$ \langle\vec x,\vec v_i \rangle =\vec x\cdot \vec v_i=x_i$$

which holds for orthogonal basis, that is for all $\vec x$ the dot product with the $i^{th}$ basis vector is equal to the component of that vector along the $i^{th}$ coordinate, such that

$$\vec x = \sum_i \langle\vec x,\vec v_i \rangle v_i$$

For infinite dimensional vector spaces refer to the answer by [P.Pet](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2785484/505767).